# Sync gradle in android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, project-online

I want to import library dependency in Android studio but I cant use in online Gradle mode .I didnt use proxy the http proxy is set to no proxy but whenever  I sync the project it gives me error that if you are behind http proxy.... !!!

Answer (score 0):

check your `gradle.settings` file and see if you set the proxy there. It automatically happens with a dialog when a new project is created or opened.

Comment: No I havent set any proxy even when I Create new project in Android studio I cant use online gradle I should turn it to offline.I have internet and I didnt set proxy but I dont know whats the problem